# GBP (£) symbol in json file created by client returns no valid response in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I have an app that accepts a URL from the user which points to a JSON file they host. The JSON file contains Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) that visualised by the app.

It works fine but in the past a few British customers have had the app crash on them (with an invalid JSON parsing error) because they have added the british pound symbol to the file. (£)

I know it is this symbol as when I have removed it from the file it has parsed fine.

Any ideas on what is causing it? If it is some UNICODE problem any idea how I can capture and cater for this before sending stuff off to the JSON parser?

===Update===

I should have investigated this a little more before posting the above and those who called me out on it were right to. Here is a more background and debugging.

I have attached the file creating the issue. I used jsonlint.com to validate it was properly formed JSON and it confirms it is.

[Link to JSON file](http://deadfrogstudios.com/appdata/pocketkpi/hskpimay.json)

I use AFNetworking2 to retrieve the json.

Here is the code in the view controller. In the code below, AFNetworking will still recognise a successful request but the responseObject is nil. Removing the £ symbol forces the object to contain data again.

```
- (void)getDataForTableUsingUrl: (NSString *)url
{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];                                       
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; 
[manager GET:@"http://deadfrogstudios.com/appdata/pocketkpi/hskpimay.json"
parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)                                                                        //Data successfully received. Begin parsing returned JSON data.
        {
            NSLog(@"Call to network...");
            DFSJSONParser *kpiParser=[[DFSJSONParser alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:responseObject];                     //Hand data off to parser class for parsing and creation of data
                                                                                                                        //models.

            kpiArray=[kpiParser kpiArrayForDashboardAtIndex:[AppController sharedAppController].selectedDashboard];     //Now that parser object is initialised obtain
                                                                                                                        //the kpi array for the selected Dashboard.

            self.navigationController.topViewController.title=[kpiParser selectedDashboardNameAtIndex:[AppController sharedAppController].selectedDashboard];   //Set navbar title to dashboard name.

            [self stopRefreshControlWasSuccess:YES];                                                                                  //Stop the refresh control.

            [self.tableView reloadData];                                                                                //Refresh table with new data.
 }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){                                                      //If the network operation fails perform this code.
         //[ErrorHandler handleError:error fatal:NO];
         [self stopRefreshControlWasSuccess:NO];
     }];
}
```

The call to DFSJSONParser creates the problem. When initWithJSONDictionary is called, using this particular file, the if(self) condition never becomes true and none of the setup code is executed. Also the debugger says the passed in json var is nil. Removing the GBP symbol (£) fixes this issue and the code executed fine.

```
- (id)initWithJSONDictionary: (NSDictionary *)json
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    if (json){                      // The JSON file contains data.
        self.kpiData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];         //Initialise the array that will hold the final result.
        jsonFromUrl=json;                                   //Set our iVar to the json file sent to the initialiser.
        [self setupDashboardsArray];
    }

}
return self;
}
```

Comment: JSON parsers take Unicode as input. There should be no issue with a wellformed JSON and a '£' within a string. If you need further help with your issue, please provide code and the JSON.

Comment: Can you check the user's URL's HTTP response and its content? You'd almost certainly want the data itself to be in UTF-8 and *also* the `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response to contain `charset=utf-8` to make sure the data reached you in a clean format. (This might well show up in a browser pointed at the URL; see http://www.thesitewizard.com/html-tutorial/pound-sign-not-showing-up-correctly.shtml for some worked examples of what might be going wrong.) Also, have you considered specifying the use of a simple combination of an amount and a currency code, like GBP?

Comment: Perhaps you can share an excerpt of the JSON in which this `£` occurred. If it's within a string, you should be fine. (Obviously, if added to a numeric value not in quotes, that would be a problem. If code that prepared JSON tried to escape it with a "\", that would be a problem.) You might also share the hex representation of this portion of the JSON, too. Bottom line, without seeing the JSON, its hard for us to say why it failed. We need [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "Amount": 123.0 = fine. "Amount": 123,0 = wrong. "Amount": £123.0 = wrong. "Amount": "£123.0" = fine, but you need to be careful processing it. "Amount": "123,45" = fine, but again you need to be careful processing it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I typed this up from memory and this was not helpful. I have enriched the original problem statement.

Comment: Every programmer should know what "crash" stands for. It is not unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan. Very useful....and of course by that I mean....not useful. Got anything constructive to add or is it just terminology correction you offer?

Comment: @MattGibson Thanks for this. Where would ensure that the HTTP response sets utf8? It's just a file I dump on rented server. I'm a little new to HTTP responses and requests.

Comment: Here is the response from the HTTP:
    { URL: http://deadfrogstudios.com/appdata/pocketkpi/hskpimay.json } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 5675;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 03 Jan 2015 11:50:43 GMT";
    Etag = "\"162b-50bbce02e0d03\"";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    "Last-Modified" = "Sat, 03 Jan 2015 10:25:26 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    Vary = "User-Agent";
    } }

Comment: So, do you have an actual example of the "bad" file? Because "application/json" is probably enough to let a client assume UTF-8, so your problem may be that the actual file isn't encoded in UTF-8. If it's been saved in Windows-1252, say, that would likely pass through all the characters *except* a pound sign the same as UTF-8, given the kind of data you're dealing with.

Comment: (Also, if you *really* want to get a handle on what's going on, and have some time to spare: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @MattGibson Hey man..thanks for the link. The file is linked in the original problem statement,

Comment: Also Matt...I suspect that is exactly what is happening. Clients are creating the file in Windows-1252. So the question is...I can't stop them from doing that. How can I cater for it....or I can't ??

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to produce data that *crashes* NSJSONSerialization then we'd want to hear about it.

Did you check that you actually have a non-nil NSData object that you pass to NSJSONSerialization (if not, it may intentionally crash).

Any invalid JSON data, it may return nil and set an error variable. If you can't handle that, that's your problem. However, millions and millions of people parse JSON data with more esoteric Unicode than a pound sign without any problems.

Are you doing something stupid like calling [aNumber doubleValue] when the number is really a string containing "£2.34"? Again, your problem.

What have you done so far to debug the problem?

Comment: Hi gnasher....a little on the unfriendly side but you are right to call me out on not providing enough info. I have enriched the description of the problem.